# Determine whether a program is a GUI or console application in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface, x11

I am programming in C++ using Qt-4 as framework, given a directory (i.e. /usr/bin) i would like to know whether the program is a GUI or console application.

I came across some information on how to do this windows and also about the inexistence of a similar (to Win) identification on Linux (within elf). Is there an alternative way to perform this on Linux?

I thought on:

- spawning each entry with QProcess and monitor it's lifetime assuming a console application would require some input and as i did not provide any, it would print to stoud an help message and exit. If it's alive after x-seconds, i would kill the process and tag it as containing a gui. It is an horrible approach and error-prone;
- run ldd  and parse the output for any libX or else. It seems a better approach although firefox, for example, would fail to be tagged as having gui.

EDIT0:
This project is an app launcher

EDIT1:
Once i have the list of programs categorized, i could launch a terminal emulator whenever the user chooses a non-graphical application

FINAL CONCLUSION:

After people answers and extra search, it really is not possible to reliably discern between console and gui applications. My best bet is to make several considerations like search for .desktop files, make a few assumptions like tools listed in utilities-only places like /bin, /sbin and /usr/sbin and so on.

Perhaps parse the output of ldd for each entry found.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no foolproof way to do this on Linux: a program can use either console or GUI as it sees fit (eg. console-only batch operations for specific command-line arguments, but GUI otherwise), or even *both at the same time* (eg. console logging while the user manipulates the GUI). How to categorize those programs then? ;) Anyway, your question looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Sorry, it was not my intention to validate my approaches. Should i remove that list?

Comment: No your question is fine as it is (it would have been downvoted otherwise). It's just that I *feel* (but I could be wrong) that detecting whether a program uses a GUI or not isn't your real problem.

Comment: In order for it to use the Qt GUI, it needs to access the Qt Libraries, assuming that it is dynamically linked.  You could go and try to prevent the connection, or replace the connection to QtGui4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program could try to start as a GUI program, and else switch to console.
(And actually some programs do exhibit such behavior, e.g. `emacs`). It could even do that at random, or because of some specific configuration...

For example, assuming that `vi` is a console program and `emacs` a graphical one, the following simple program may randomly be GUI or console:

```
 #include <unistd.h>

 int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    if (getpid()%2 == 0)
      { argv[0]="vi"; execv("/usr/bin/vi", argv); }
    else
      { argv[0]="emacs"; execv("/usr/bin/emacs", argv); }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
```

The simplest (but not foolproof) way of doing that is testing if `getenv("DISPLAY")` returns NULL. A more elaborate way would be to call `XOpenDisplay` which returns `NULL` on failure (and several X11 toolkits do that).

So, your question does not have a precise answer, and does not really make sense.

You could use `ldd` .... and add manually exceptions like `firefox`.

Comment: Perhaps i did not write clearly enough, your sugestions regarding getenv and XOpenDisplay are not applicable to my case. I am not trying to figure out if i can open a gui. 

My program is a launcher, so what i wish is to be able to help the user out by launching a terminal whenever it chooses a non graphical application. 

It's not a critical functionallity, just seemed to be a nice and challenging to implement feature.

Comment: But I am trying to explain that what you want to achieve is in principle impossible. Being a GUI program is not even well defined.

Comment: Thank you Basile, after the answers here and from the results of my search, i am conviced that it's impossible to reliably discern between them.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing (yet another) app launcher, please follow what the people who have created all of the other app launchers did and use the [`.desktop` files](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html). That specification already defines the `Terminal` option which is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I was trying to avoid .desktop files only approach exactly for the reason you mentioned: everyone else did that way in order to iconify and stuff.

My attempt is to index custom-placed installations and whatever executables i find in PATH. 

I will blend your sugestion with what i am doing. Some places like /bin, /sbin and /usr/sbin are console utilities mainly, so it's fairly safe to assume that.

Comment: On my system (a Gentoo box which doesn't contain that many extra binaries), ``/usr/sbin/latencytop`` and ``/usr/sbin/pppgetpass.gtk`` both link to ``libQtGui.so.4``.

Comment: Thank you for your observation, in fact the /usr/sbin on some of the machines which i have access have lots of gui software (Debian and Arch)